# Is there a size limit to the amount of data you can send to a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is there a size limit to the amount of data you can send to a WCF service?
I send an array of objects over and when the array gets to be a certain size, I get a 404 bad request exception.

Is this a limit of httpHosting? Would another type of hosting work better?

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/wcf-maximum-array-length-quota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a maximum array size and maximum content size. 
Here is the XML (put in your App.config) to increase the size.

specify net tcp binding config:

```
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="TCPSession"  
closeTimeout="01:01:00"
            openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00"
            transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>
```

Comment: You can also use ReaderQuotas (in the netTcpBinding):
            &lt;readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
               maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647"
               maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
               maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" /&gt;

This will also work for basicHttpBinding