# Server Error 500 using json data

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting an error and I cant find a solution.

I have a desktop application (c#), that connects to a WCF web service. When I send some data (10 item of some class), everything works ok. But, when I use more data (maybe more than 15 items), I get a Server Error 500. Why is this happening?. Is there any size restriction?

How can it be solved?.

Comment: What is different about the additionl 5+ items that you are sending..? have you analyzed that..? are there any timeout settings in the .config file ..? it's hard to tell based on a description alone perhaps you can describe or show what the content as well as the datatype(s) look like that you are passing

Comment: The best approach is to enable tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your WCF service and see the exact reason on why you are getting a 500 error code. If its to do with the size of data being sent you can increase your readerQuotas of your bindings on both client and server

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a size restriction in your bindings.  There is a maximum size in your bindings.  Check this post for more information:

[Is there a size limit to the amount of data you can send to a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344463/is-there-a-size-limit-to-the-amount-of-data-you-can-send-to-a-wcf-service)

You should also look in your event log -- might have some useful information to track down the issue.