# Anyone seen this problem with protobuf-net over net.msmq

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net, netmsmqbinding

I am seeing a problem where I send large messages over wcf net.msmq using protobuf-net and get the following error:

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'DeliverData'. End element 'proto' from namespace 'http://mynamespace' expected

If message size is under 16k, it works

If I remove protobuf-net, it works

If I switch to basichttp, it works

But if message size is over 16k, using protobuf-net, over net.msmq, I get the error.  I have set maxBufferPoolSize and maxReceivedMessageSize sufficiently large, it does not help.

Has anyone else seen this?  Has anyone else used protobuf-net + net.msmq for large messages and gotten it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the delay - holiday etc. No, I haven't seen a specific problem with that. The fact that it calls out the "End element" suggests that it is in the xml layer at the time (which is before protobuf-net *really* gets involved). Do you have any way that I could reliably reproduce this?

---

After investigation, the problem here appears to be a WCF's reader-quotas; the exception appears to be swallowed by MSMQ, so wasn't immediately obvious. This can be fixed [in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/wcf-maximum-array-length-quota), or in code (if you are setting up your bindings manually) by referencing System.Runtime.Serialization and increasing the binding's `.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength` appropriately. The maximum allowed value is `2147483647`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have emailed you sample code that demonstrates the problem