# .net Serializer Deserialization failing when string is greater than 32768 characters long

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have a method like this:

```
var stringReader = new StringReader(ruleSetXmlDefinition);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
var serializer = new WorkflowMarkupSerializer();
return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as RuleSet;
```

When the ruleSetXmlDefinition is greater than 32768 characters long I get the following error:

> Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 1,
>   position 32768.

How can I change this so that it can handle strings of any length?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you can configure Wcf to accept bigger arrays, see also this answer:

- [Maximum array length quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/maximum-array-length-quota)

Something like

```
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ImageResizerServiceContract" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10"
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                                          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                                          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                                          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                                          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
        </binding>

</netTcpBinding>
```

Comment: This method is not being exposed over WCF, it is just a simple local method

Comment: @DavidWard: I noticed you didn't say so, yet WorkflowMarkupSerializer is part of WCF so the configuration might apply. You can search MSDN for a way to globally override the defaults

Comment: Thanks for this but I am unable to find any further information about setting WCF config globally. Also, this code works fine when below the character limit and I don't have any WCF config anywhere in the application so don't see how this could help

Comment: @DavidWard: huh, that would be because of default values? Well, sorry I can't help you any further a.t.m.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this issue and unfortunately it was something really obvious...the string I was passing in was actually being truncated so the issue was actually that the xml was not well formed.