# WCF pass maximum byte array

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, wcf-binding

I am trying to pass large byte array to **wcf service** from windows phone application. I have tried all possible way's to pass large byte array but I couldn't pass it.

Here is my **web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <!--<binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>-->
    <binding closeTimeout="01:30:00" 
      openTimeout="01:30:00" receiveTimeout="01:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00" transferMode="Streamed"
      maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967295">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" /> 
      <security mode="None">             
      </security>
    </binding>    
  </basicHttpBinding>    
</bindings>   

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding"  scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I have used the max received message size i.e. `2147483646`. Now I will show my

**ServiceReferences.ClientConfig**

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/WebService/Service1.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="MyService.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am passing following parameter to my wcf service method

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
public string GetDataUsingDataContract(byte[] fileByte,string fileName,string folderName)
{
}
```

I have searched a lot and I found one similar example [Maximum array length quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/maximum-array-length-quota)

But I heard that windows phone 8 doesn't support `netTcpBinding`. I have read that we can pass **2GB** file to wcf service. How can I pass max byte array? I am stuck with this problem. Can someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: `The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

Comment: `An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: Is that the full exception stack?

Comment: Yes. Above one in inner exception

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common exception - have a look at the following posts on msdn social:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/4fe7c526-510d-46ab-acac-9719e696f7db/an-exception-of-type-systemservicemodelcommunicationexception-occurred-in
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/61f1060f-846e-4e7d-b8ff-c2956e0a8677/visual-studio-2012-windows-phone-8-wcf-systemservicemodelcommunicationexception

Both seem to point to a problem with the windows 8 phone emulator. Instructions on how to work around this here:
http://countofmontecito.com/2012/11/13/wcf-and-windows-phone-8/

Full documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Getting an error `The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

Comment: Is my `web.config` and `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` is correct?