# Connecting to WCF running as a Windows Service on another computer

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a WinForms client application. I have the WCF server running on another computer as a part of a Windows Service that I wrote. I first tried `NetPipeBinding` and now `NetTcpBinding`. I did open up 2 ports in *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security*. The server OS is *Windows Server 2016*.

Here is the server code:

```
public Boolean CreatePipeServer(out string logEntry)
{
    try
    {
        NetTcpBinding ipcBinding = new NetTcpBinding()
        {
            Security = new NetTcpSecurity()
            {
                Mode = SecurityMode.None,
                Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None,
                    ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None,
                },
            },
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 6553600,
            MaxBufferSize = 6553600,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6553600,
            MaxConnections = 1000,
            ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
            {
                MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
                MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647,
                MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
            },
        };

        // Instantiate: Host Service
        Uri uriMex = new Uri("http://localhost:8000");
        this.ServiceParent.ServiceIpcAppToService.HostIpcAppToService = new ServiceHost(typeof(IpcAppToService), uriMex);

        // Instantiate: Endpoint
        Uri uriService = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8004/StampIpcAppToService");
        this.ServiceParent.ServiceIpcAppToService.HostIpcAppToService.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(StampIpc.IIpcAppToService), ipcBinding, uriService);

        // Instantiate: Service Meta Behavior
        ServiceMetadataBehavior ipcSmb = this.ServiceParent.ServiceIpcAppToService.HostIpcAppToService.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        if (null == ipcSmb)
        {
            ipcSmb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
            {
                HttpGetEnabled = true,
            };
            this.ServiceParent.ServiceIpcAppToService.HostIpcAppToService.Description.Behaviors.Add(ipcSmb);
            ServiceDescription serviceDescription = this.ServiceParent.ServiceIpcAppToService.HostIpcAppToService.Description;
        }

        // Instantiate: MEX Biding
        Binding ipcMexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
        this.ServiceParent.ServiceIpcAppToService.HostIpcAppToService.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), ipcMexBinding, "MEX");

        // Capture events.
        ...

        // Start the service.
        this.ServiceParent.ServiceIpcAppToService.HostIpcAppToService.Open();

        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception) { }

return false;
}
```

I am attempting to test a valid communication link by going to the `Add > Service Reference...` in `Visual Studio 2019`. No matter what I type, I keep receiving errors of one sort or the other. Currently, I placed:

```
net.tcp://10.10.70.134:8004/StampIpcAppToService
```

That throws the error:

> The URI prefix is not recognized.
>       Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://10.10.70.134:8004/StampIpcAppToService'.
>       Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://10.10.70.134:8004/StampIpcAppToService'.
>       If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I already have the client code, but if I cannot get the `Add Service Reference` working, then the client code definitely will not work.

The code above starts as part of the `OnStart` event for the `Windows Service`.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The answer resolved the direct question above, however my real code uses code similar to the server side and I receive an error. I modified the code based on the answer and a bit of debugging. Current code is:

```
    public static Boolean ConnectToService()
    {
        ComAppToService.IsPipeAppToService = false;
        ComAppToService.IpcPipeFactory = null;
        Program.HostIpcAppToService = null;
        try
        {
            // Instantiate: Callack
            var ipcCallback = new IpcAppToServiceBack();
            InstanceContext ipcCallbackInstance = new InstanceContext(ipcCallback);

            // Instantiate: Endpoint
            Uri ipcUri = new Uri($"http://10.10.70.134:8000/mex");
            EndpointAddress ipcEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(ipcUri);

            // Instantiate: Binding
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/maximum-array-length-quota
            WSDualHttpBinding ipcBindingHttp = new WSDualHttpBinding()
            {
                Security = new WSDualHttpSecurity() { Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None },
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 6553600,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6553600,
                ClientBaseAddress = ipcUri,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
                    MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647,
                    MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
                },
            };

            // Instantiate: Factory
            ComAppToService.IpcPipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IIpcAppToService>(ipcCallbackInstance, ipcBindingHttp, ipcEndpoint);
            Program.HostIpcAppToService = ComAppToService.IpcPipeFactory.CreateChannel();

            // Open: Callback
            Program.HostIpcAppToService.OpenCallback(IpcCallbackDest.App);
            ComAppToService.IsPipeAppToService = true;

            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception.
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Exception:

> InnerException = {"The message with Action
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions betwee...

**UPDATE 2 (reflects updated answer)**

Using `NetTcpBinding` generates this error:

Using URI:

```
Uri ipcUri = new Uri($"net.tcp://10.10.70.134:8004");
```

Generates

```
Message = "There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://jmr-engineering:8004/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."
```

Using URI:

```
Uri ipcUri = new Uri($"net.tcp://10.10.70.134:8000");
```

Generates

```
Message = "You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint."

InnerException = {"Expected record type 'PreambleAck', found '72'."}
```

**THE ANSWER:**

The accepted answer needs a modification. Abraham did not have the correct `URI`, however he pointed me to `SvcUtil.exe`, which gave that to me.

URI:

```
net.tcp://10.10.70.134:8004/StampIpcAppToService
```

I do need `NetTcpBinding`, so the final client side code is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the ipc application to service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Boolean.</returns>
    public static Boolean ConnectToService()
    {
        ComAppToService.IsPipeAppToService = false;
        ComAppToService.IpcPipeFactory = null;
        Program.HostIpcAppToService = null;
        try
        {
            // Instantiate: Callack
            var ipcCallback = new IpcAppToServiceBack();
            InstanceContext ipcCallbackInstance = new InstanceContext(ipcCallback);

            // Instantiate: Endpoint
            Uri ipcUri = new Uri($"net.tcp://10.10.70.134:8004/StampIpcAppToService");
            EndpointAddress ipcEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(ipcUri);

            // Instantiate: Binding
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/maximum-array-length-quota
            NetTcpBinding ipcBindingHttp = new NetTcpBinding()
            {
                Security = new NetTcpSecurity() { Mode = SecurityMode.None },
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 6553600,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6553600,
                MaxBufferSize = 6553600,
                MaxConnections = 1000,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
                    MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647,
                    MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
                },
            };

            // Instantiate: Factory
            ComAppToService.IpcPipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IIpcAppToService>(ipcCallbackInstance, ipcBindingHttp, ipcEndpoint);
            Program.HostIpcAppToService = ComAppToService.IpcPipeFactory.CreateChannel();

            // Open: Callback
            Program.HostIpcAppToService.OpenCallback(IpcCallbackDest.App);
            ComAppToService.IsPipeAppToService = true;

            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception.
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here is the output of the `output.config` from the `SvcUtil.exe`. The `IpcAppToService.cs` file was useless, but the config file was definitely helpful.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IIpcAppToService">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8004/StampIpcAppToService"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IIpcAppToService"
            contract="IIpcAppToService" name="NetTcpBinding_IIpcAppToService" />
        </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding service reference relies on the service metadata address instead of the service address. According to your above settings, the Uri in your Adding service reference dialog should be,

> http://10.10.70.134:8000/mex

In general, we have to expose the metadata either by adding a `Mex` endpoint or by the `HttpGetEnabled` property of the `ServiceMetedataBehavior`. Subsequently, the client-side could generate a client proxy by using the `SVCUtil` tool.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
In `Visual Studio`, `Adding Service reference` dialog is a shortcut to generate a client proxy. It relies on the `Mex` service endpoint. The `Mex` endpoint address is necessary for the shortcut.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**
Duplex communication means we should use `Nettcpbinding`(supports duplex) on the client-side.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding()
            {
                Security = new NetTcpSecurity
                {
                    Mode = SecurityMode.None
                },
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 6553600,
                MaxBufferSize = 6553600,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6553600,
                MaxConnections = 1000,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
                    MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647,
                    MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
                },
            };
            //replace it with your practical service address.
            Uri uri = new Uri("net.tcp://10.157.13.69:8004");
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = service.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }

    }

    //the service contract shared between the client-side and the server-side.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test();

    }
```

Comment: The answer does resolve the direct question stated, but my code uses a client side counterpart to the server side code, not an Add-Service Reference, see client side code added to my question. I receive the exception stated. I modified the client side based on the answer and debugging. VS stated that I had to use `Dual` and not `Basic`. Still, I get an error.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger , please see the updated reply.  we are supposed to keep the binding between the client-side and the server-side consistent when calling SOAP service, which guarantees the communication channel could be established.